# How can I stop IE from compounding relative font sizes in pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have some icons that are set via pseudoelement in CSS, like this:

```
.button a:before { 
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: font-awesome; 
  content: "*";  
}
```

And there are other, similar declarations elsewhere, like

```
.button .otherclass a:before { 
  font-size: 1.35em; 
}
```

This works fine with modern web browsers, but IE >= 9 compounds all the font sizes, so that the resulting icon is enormous (like 5 times its size). How can I prevent this from happening?

(BTW, the actual code with the problem [is here](https://github.com/mlaa/cbox-mla/blob/master/style.scss).)

Comment: IE what? Be specific with your versions. It matters.

Comment: Fair enough. Updated. (It's IE versions >= 9. Bizarrely, this issue doesn't pop up in IE 8 or below.)

Comment: This is a known issue, FYI. See https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813398/ie-11-css-before-with-font-size-in-em-units-ignores-css-precedence-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in IE, as reported on the [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813398/ie-11-css-before-with-font-size-in-em-units-ignores-css-precedence-rules) page mentioned by @Aibrean, but the page also shows that Microsoft does not admit that this is a bug (they say they cannot reproduce it). It can be reproduced in IE 11 on Win 7 with the following simple document:

```html
<style>
.foo, .bar:before { 
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "X";  
}
.bar:before { 
  font-size: 5em; 
} 
</style>
X<span class=foo>X</span>
<span class=bar>bar</span>
```

The second X should be 5 times as big as normal X, but it is actually 10 times as big in IE, since IE incorrectly multiplies the effects of `2em` and `5em`.

The workaround, it seems, is to organize your style sheet so that the font size of generated content is set once only for each element. That is, so that there are no two `font-size` declarations that apply to the same `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element.

Comment: I got around this by using absolute font sizes, i.e. `16px` instead of `1em`. Messy, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly better solution than using absolute font-sizes, and that is to use rem inside the :before or :after declaration.

em and rem units are based of the default font-size (commonly 16px, so 1rem = 1em = 16px) so if the user changes their default font then your font will change too. However rem units do not compound.

rem support is growing but you can use both (if you don't need compounding):

```
font-size: 2em
font-size: 2rem
```

and then those browsers (e.g. IE8) that don't support rem will use em. And as IE8 doesn't have the compounding issue to which you refer, this actually works nicely.